# JavaScript $('myDiv').style.direction always returns blank?

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs

I'm trying to get the direction property for the element. I have this code:

```
document.write('<div style="position: absolute; display: none;" id="menuDiv"></div>');
```

And in my .css file I have:

```
#menuDiv {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Then, using prototype, I'm trying to query the direction for that div:

```
alert( $('menuDiv').style.direction );
```

But for some reason I'm always getting blank, never an 'rtl' value which I need to find out whether current style is left-to-right or not so that the menu can be positioned properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$('menuDiv').getStyle('direction')`. The element's "style" property may not contain the style as applied by the stylesheet.